# Javascript script finding specific number

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote this little script:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('option')
 for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
 var val = a[i].innerHTML.split('   ').join('')
  if (val == "39") {
   alert("gg");
  }
}
```

To go through this:

```
<select name="id" autocomplete="off" class="custom-select">
    <option value="-1">Choose size</option>
    <option value="32286">37</option>
    <option value="32287">37,5</option>
    <option value="32288">38</option>
    <option value="32289">39</option>
    <option value="32290">39.5</option>
    <option value="32291">40</option>
    <option value="32292">40,5</option>
    <option value="32293">41,5</option>
    <option value="32294">42</option>
</select>
```

and see if any of the innerHTML equals exactly 39 and alert me if so.

But for some reason it is not working.
It all looks good to me. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

val seems to contain string with whitespaces, you can use trim() to remove those before checking.

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('option')
 for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
 var val = a[i].innerHTML.split('   ').join('')
  if (val.trim() == "39") {
   alert("gg");
  }
}
```

Comment: You can do this, but it's extra unnecessary work. Just use `indexOf()`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus that would be wrong if the string changes and contains 39 like 390.

Comment: That is true. I was working under the assumption that the test string was known to be exact and unique (after all, it wouldn't make sense for two options to have the same value or to test for a value that isn't the value you want).

Answer (score 1):

Try using [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) - this will maintain your requirement for the value being *exactly* 39.

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('option');
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  if (a[i].innerHTML.trim() === "39") {
    alert("gg");
  }
}
```

Comment: You can do this, but it's extra unnecessary work. Just use `indexOf()`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus `indexOf()` will also match 39,5

Comment: That is true. I was working under the assumption that the test string was known to be exact and unique (after all, it wouldn't make sense for two options to have the same value or to test for a value that isn't the value you want).

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking for exactly 3 spaces to split on and since your source code shows each `option` with many more than 3 spaces, there are still spaces left over after you do your operation.  This means that `val` is still going to contain spaces and your code assumes that all the spaces were removed.

You could remove all the spaces with:

```
var val = a[i].innerHTML.replace(/\s+/g);
```

Or, you could use the `.trim()` string method that removes leading and trailing spaces but all that is not necessary at all. Just check the `textContent` (not `.innerHTML` since you are trying to read any HTML) of the `option` elements using `indexOf()`, which looks at the entire string and returns the index location of the found string or `-1` if the string wasn't found.

As a side note, why would your `option` elements even have all that whitespace in them in the first place?

```js
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('option')
 for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
   // Just check the contents of the element to see if the specified string exists in it
   if (a[i].textContent.indexOf("39") > -1) {
   alert("gg");
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="id" autocomplete="off" class="custom-select">
    <option value="-1">Choose size</option>
    <option value="32286">        37        </option>
    <option value="32287">      37,5 </option>
    <option value="32288">    38     </option>
                                                                                                        <option value="32289">
                                39
                                                            </option>
                                                                                                        <option value="32290">39.5</option>
                                                                                                        <option value="32291">
                                40
                                                            </option>
                                                                                                        <option value="32292">
                                40,5
                                                            </option>
                                                                                                        <option value="32293">
                                41,5
                                                            </option>
                                                                                                        <option value="32294">
                                42
                                                            </option>
                                        </select>
```